# Multiline String List

Tags: python

I'm currently making an in editor game in Python, the idea is to create a modifiable game board using lists, so far, this is my implementation:

```
gBoard = [
['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08',]
['09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16',]
['17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24',]
['25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32',]
['33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40',]
['41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48',]
['49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56',]
['57','58','59','60','61','62','63','64',]]
```

This can be printed easily to the console (print(gBoard)) and can be replaced by the user with their token by typing the relevant number

*However* when it's run, I fall into this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Nu Voute De Merde\Uni Work\Drive Backup\Programming Assessment Two\Assessment2.py", line 51, in <module>
    ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08',]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Is there a better / easier way of creating a gameboard like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move the comma outside the closing bracket in each list.

Notice the comma after "08", "16"....

```
gBoard = [
['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08'],
['09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16'],
['17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24'],
['25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32'],
['33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40'],
['41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48'],
['49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56'],
['57','58','59','60','61','62','63','64']]
```

Comment: I don't know if I can swear here, but I certainly did alot in real life, thanks so much! I can't believe I didn't see that haha